# PHP function to adapt texte not working with special characters?

Tags: php, mbstring

i'm struggling with a function that adapts a text depending of the first letter of a string.

```
            $str = "élo";

            function deD($str) { 
            return (in_array(mb_strtolower($str[0]), array('a', 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ê', 'h', 'i', 'o', 'u')) ? 'd\'' : 'de ').$str;
            }
            
            echo deD($str).'</br>';
            echo $str[0];
```

OUTPUT:
de élo
�

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
d'élo
é

Basically, mb_strtolower should prevent all special characters to be miss-read.
I tried different options, but i still get it wrong.
I'd like the function to work with all accent types.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot from France !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set utf-8 encoding for the file. Try to put this at the top:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Then, instead of `$str[0]`, use `mb_substr($str, 0, 1)`

```
function deD($str) {
    return (in_array(mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str, 0, 1)), array('a', 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ê', 'h', 'i', 'o', 'u')) ? 'd\'' : 'de ').$str;
}

$str = 'élo';

echo deD($str).'<br>';
echo mb_substr($str, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Did you just checked the answer on the Facebook post haha ? Nice one !

Answer (score 0):

The default national language setting (NLS) used in mbstring. Note that this option automagically defines mbstring.internal_encoding and mbstring.internal_encoding should be placed after mbstring.language in php.ini

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php